# Sharepoint publishing

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have scenario that User need to submit the suggestion about particular topic once he submit it will be reviewed and published .Once published user can give like,comments and unlike. How to do that in share point and also need to capture like unlike and comments .Please help with code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create List: Discussion Board it's OOTB SharePoint Online List you have here comments, approval based on versioning,
2. List Settings > Versioning Settings > Set:

Require content approval for submitted items: Yes

Create a version each time you edit an item in this list: No

Who should see draft items in this list: Only users who can approve items

3. Permissions for this discussion board, set properly permissions, set Approve for users who should approve new discussions.
4. Rating Settings > Rating Settings: Yes, Which voting: Likes

You have here everything you need :) Hope it is what you want!

Comment: You have been busy today :)  great explanation.  Have an up doot.

Comment: Thank you so much! List of rating count also taking in sharepoint OOTB itself?

Comment: Mark it as answer please :) which list of rating count? you can probably do a view, where you will show title, rating count and do ordering with rating.